# Usage of 的: The first day of (or without of) a fast?

Tags: grammar

Is correct to translate "The first day of a fast" (fast — in religious meaning) as: 第一天快? Or the better to use 的: 第一天的快?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese StackExchange. The details of the question in its current state needs rewriting, particularly on the translation of the word for "fast". Could you reference an English-Chinese dictionary and edit the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When 'fast' refers to no food/drink/both/[sometimes sex] for a period of time by religion (Ramadan, for example), it's "斋戒."

When 'fast' refers to no food/drink/both for a period of time for political reasons (hunger strike), it's "绝食/绝食抗议."

When 'fast' refers to no food/drink/both for a period of time for medical purposes (blood test/surgery), it's "禁食 (verb)/空腹（adj.)."

"快" means "quick/fast/high speed" in adj.  "about to/nearly" in adv.

In you case, I would say "斋戒(的)第一天。"